Does FindWindowEx() work differently in Windows 11?
I was successfully using FindWindowEx() for getting a console window handle. The window search was conducted by window title. The problem is that this method stopped working in Windows 11.
Under Windows 10, FindWindowEx (-, -, -, "My_Console_Title") returns a valid handle to My_Console, which allowed me to send messages to it. Under Windows 11, the same call returns an invalid handle.

No, FindWindowEx() did not change. What probably changed is the implementation of the console host. Finding a window by its title alone has never been a robust solution and now you understand why, too.

Is the console window attached to the process that is calling FindWindowEx()? If so, then just use GetConsoleWindow() instead.

New Microsoft Windows Terminal allows to keep multiple consoles under single host window. Can be turned off if you really need old console.

The problem is not the searching by title (instead of by class). I was using an "unique" name. Actually Microsoft has acknowledge that there are "a rare issue where FindWindow and FindWindowEx might return an unexpected window." [https://acesse.dev/G5v59]

You can easily verify whether this is the issue by running the code under Windows 11 23H2 (which includes the fix). Note that the issue notes that it would return an "unexpected window" which does not match your description that reads "invalid handle". Vastly more likely is that you made assumptions about implementation details and those details changed.

The issue has been fixed in Windows 11 Insider Preview Build 25231. You could refer to the link:https://blogs.windows.com/windows-insider/2022/10/27/announcing-windows-11-insider-preview-build-25231/

Fixed a rare issue where FindWindow and FindWindowEx might return an
unexpected window.

